# MySQL Find difference in records against previous day based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Just a note before you read, I have created a query to achieve the below but just wanted to double check if i was doing anything wrong or if there was a more efficient way of doing it.

I have a set of records as below in a MySQL table (press run code snippet to view the table)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 (Windows)"/>
 <meta name="created" content="2018-06-21T09:33:19.600000000"/>
 <meta name="changed" content="2018-06-21T09:42:20.756000000"/>
 
 <style type="text/css">
  body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Calibri"; font-size:x-small }
 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <colgroup width="85"></colgroup>
 <colgroup width="84"></colgroup>
 <colgroup width="110"></colgroup>
 <colgroup width="127"></colgroup>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="left"><font color="#000000">Date</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">PortfolioId</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">ISIN</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">AssetOwnsership</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43269" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">18/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1234" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">1234</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B069DV22</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">1</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B069DV22</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1.18" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">1.18</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.1298" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0.1298</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="82294" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">82294</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="82294" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">82294</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43270" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">19/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="82294" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">82294</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.1378" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0.1378</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B069DV22</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1.25" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">1.25</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.1175" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0.1175</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B6774691</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.1" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0.1</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="21" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1234" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">1234</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.5" sdnum="2057;"><font color="#000000">0.5</font></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- ************************************************************************** -->
</body>

</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is find the differences between today and yesterday for the column AssetOwnsership to show an increase or decrease of a current position based the match of two columns (ISIN and Portfolio ID) and also output any new records/positions for Today.

Based on the above data set, the output should be:(press run code snippet to view the table)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 (Windows)"/>
 <meta name="created" content="2018-06-21T10:02:42.397000000"/>
 <meta name="changed" content="2018-06-21T10:03:10.865000000"/>
 
 <style type="text/css">
  body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Liberation Sans"; font-size:x-small }
 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <colgroup span="4" width="85"></colgroup>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="32" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">Date</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">PortfolioId</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">ISIN</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">AssetOwnsership</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="32" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">GB00B069DV22</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.0700000000000001" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">0.07</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="32" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="-0.0123" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">-0.0123</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="32" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="3521" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">3521</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">GB00B6774691</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.1" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">0.1</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="32" align="right" sdval="43271" sdnum="2057;0;DD/MM/YYYY"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">20/06/2018</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="1234" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">1234</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="left"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">GB00B6774699</font></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="right" sdval="0.5" sdnum="2057;"><font face="Liberation Serif" color="#000000">0.5</font></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- ************************************************************************** -->
</body>

</html>
```

I have created the SQL Query below which provides this data for me: (assuming todays date is 20/06/2018 to run against the data)

```
SELECT *, (case WHEN SUM(b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership)=0 then b.assetownsership
else SUM(b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership)
end) Difference, (case WHEN SUM(b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership)<0 then "S"
else "B"
end) BuySell
FROM performance.Assetallocation a
JOIN performance.Assetallocation b on b.isin = a.isin and b.portfolioID=a.portfolioID 
where b.date>=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')-1
group by a.portfolioID, a.isin
```

My Questions are:

- Is there a better way of achieving this?
- Am I doing anything wrong in my query even though it seems like it provides the right ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a better form of your query:

```
select a.portfolioID, a.isin,
       sum(case when a.date = curdate()
                then a.assetownsership
                when a.date = curdate() - interval 1 day 
                then - a.assetownsership
           end) as difference,
       (case when sum(case when a.date = curdate()
                           then a.assetownsership
                           when a.date = curdate() - interval 1 day 
                           then - a.assetownsership
                      end) < 0
              then 'S' else 'B'
         end) as BuySell
from performance.Assetallocation a
where a.date >= curdate() - interval 1 day
group by a.portfolioID, a.isin;
```

Notes:

- This uses conditional aggregation, so no `join` is necessary.
- This assumes that `date` is really a date.  If it has a time component, use the `date()` function or similar logic.
- The only unaggregated expressions in the `select` should be expressions in the `group by`.  Hence, no `select *`.
- When doing date/time comparisons, use native string operations.  Don't convert date/times to strings unless you really have to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the post and the explanation, this resolves the issue and works perfectly. From my testing so far.

Comment: may i also ask @Gordon Linoff if you could recommend any training courses for sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query needs to be sightly change, as you need to find difference between today and yesterday based on protfolioID and ISIN, it should be like

```
SELECT 
    b.date, 
    (CASE WHEN (b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership)<=0 THEN b.assetownsership
        ELSE (b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership) END) Difference, 
    (CASE WHEN (b.assetownsership-a.assetownsership)<0 THEN "S" ELSE "B" END) BuySell
FROM performance.Assetallocation a
JOIN performance.Assetallocation b ON b.isin = a.isin AND b.portfolioID=a.portfolioID 
WHERE b.date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y') 
        AND a.date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')-1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this doesn't return the additional new records/output for today as per the output: